# No default option is configured for constraint Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Time

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to set time property of type `Time` to Doctrine entity `Availability`

```
  class Availability{
       /**
        * @var int
        *
        * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
       private $id;

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="time", nullable=true)
        * @Assert\Time(message = "wrong time format")
        */
       private $startTime;

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", type="time", nullable=true)
        * @Assert\Time(message = "wrong time format")
        */
       private $endTime;
    }
```

In controller I am setting time by creating `Time` object:

```
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Time;

    /////

    $availability = new Availability();

    $availability->setStartTime(new Time('18:00:00'));
    $availability->setEndTime(new Time('21:00:00'));
```

I have this **error**

> No default option is configured for constraint
>   Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Time (500 Internal Server
>   Error)

Comment: Why do you put a **constraint** instance into entity? It has  validation purpose, not being a property of entity.

Comment: @dragoste when I typed new Time() it auto-added itself in `use`

Comment: Rotfl, what? You have no idea what you're doing, do you? It's hard to help you here since I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: try with `new \Time(` instead of `new Time(`

Comment: @dragoste yeah, I am new to Symfony. I am trying to figure out how to save time in db

Comment: @Matteo I tried what you said, now I have this: `Attempted to load class "Time" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Time"? (500 Internal Server Error)`

Comment: @blahblah Matteo is just doing blind guess on what you're doing. Apparently he's wrong. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The 'auto-adding' you mentionned in comments is sometimes misleading and put you in bad situations specially when you are just starting to learn something.

`startTime` and `endTime` are of type `time` , Doctrine defines the time field as follows :

> time: Type that maps a SQL TIME to a PHP DateTime object.

So you need to pass a `DateTime` object to your setters and not a `Time` constraint. 
Something like this may work for you :

```
$availability = new Availability();

$availability->setStartTime(new \DateTime('now'));
$availability->setEndTime(new \DateTime('another date')); // <- change another date
```

Comment: There should be a backslash before `DateTime` to work, since controller probably has some namespace too. Also there's no `Time` class in PHP and I don't think, OP has his own here.

Comment: but I only need time of day, I don't need date. Is it possible just to save hour and minutes in db at all?

Comment: @blahblah there's a difference between what object type you use in PHP and what's stored in DB. That's what Doctrine's mapping is for.

Comment: Here's a table that shows you how Doctrine's type is mapped to particular field type in particular RDBMS http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#mapping-matrix